# What causes the lack of focus due to sleep deprivation? What are the outcomes of this?

Tags: sleep, attention, cognitive

When one is sleepy and one attempt's to work on something cognitively demanding, such as doing algebra in one's head, or trying to imagine a house's interior in detail, what causes the "resistance" to focus on such problems?

I feel like part of the problem is related to circadian rhythm, particularly with respect to cortisol as a vigilance heightener.  Surely there is more to this though.

Comment: To me, this question is almost equivalent to _"Why do we need sleep?"_